# Map a function to values of specified keys in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a convenient way to map a function to specified keys in a dictionary?

Ie, given

```
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
```

would like to map a function, say f, to keys "a" and "c":

```
{"a": f(1), "b": 2, "c": f(3)}
```

**EDIT**

Looking for methods that will not update the input dictionary.

Comment: I'd do: `use_f = {'a', 'b'}` then `{k: v if k not in use_f else f(v) for k, v in d.items()}`

Comment: Thanks, this idea works. I wrote a variation: `def map_at_keys(d,f,keys): return {k: f(v) if k in keys else v for k,v in d.items()}`

Comment: Cool, glad to help! Yes, it makes sense to put this into a function.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
output_dict = {k: f(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Note that `f(v)` will be evaluated (called) immediately and its return values will be stored as the dictionary's values.

If you want to store the function and call it later (with the arguments already stored) you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial


def f(n):
    print(n * 2)


d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}

output_dict = {k: partial(f, v) for k, v in d.items()}

output_dict['b']()
# 4
```

If you only want **specific keys** mapped you can of course not use `.items` and just override those keys:

```
d['a'] = partial(f, d['a'])
```

or more generalized

```
keys = ('a', 'c')
for key in keys:
    d[key] = partial(f, d[key])
```

Comment: Thanks. However, and I should have stated this in the Q, that I don't want the input dictionary updated `d[key]=...`, nor necessarily instantiate a new variable d2 - eg perhaps to inspect the modified return value. Can you modify your answer?

Comment: @alancalvitti So you don't want to modify the original dictionary, but you also do not want to create a new one. There is no third option...

Comment: the use case is to either print the return value of this selective map eg `d.map_on_keys(f,["a","c"])`  or to globally  set `d2 =  d.map_on_keys(f,["a","c"])`